# Слить массива на PHP по ключу

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть несколько массивов
выглядят следующим образом
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
            [1] => TRUCK, OM904LA-E2, (2002-07), 4.3D, 100/136, 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
            [1] => BUS, OM904LA-E2, (2001-07), 4.3D, 125/170, 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
            [1] => UNIMOG/WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-E3, (2001-12), 4.3D, 130/177, 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
            [1] => TRUCK, OM904LA-EPA98, (2002-07), 4.3D, 127/173, 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
            [1] => ATEGO1418/1518, OM904LA, 4.3D, 127/173, 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => FREIGHTLINER
            [1] => OM904LA-MEXICO, (2000-03), 4.3D, 127/173, 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => FREIGHTLINER
            [1] => WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-EPA, (2001-05), 4.3D, 135/184
        )

)
```

Как слить массивы так чтоб получить приблизительно такой результат

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => MERCEDES-BENZ
                [1] => TRUCK, OM904LA-E2, (2002-07), 4.3D, 100/136, BUS, OM904LA-E2, (2001-07), 4.3D, 125/170, UNIMOG/WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-E3, (2001-12), 4.3D, 130/177, TRUCK, OM904LA-EPA98, (2002-07), 4.3D, 127/173, ATEGO1418/1518, OM904LA, 4.3D, 127/173, 
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => FREIGHTLINER
                [1] => OM904LA-MEXICO, (2000-03), 4.3D, 127/173, WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-EPA, (2001-05), 4.3D, 135/184
            )

)
```

Comment: циклом, циклом. пробегаешься по массиву, формируешь новый массив - ключ = нулевой элемент подмассива, значение = совпадающие по ключу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```php
$cars = array(
    array(
        "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "TRUCK, OM904LA-E2, (2002-07), 4.3D, 100/136, "
    ),
    array(
        "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "BUS, OM904LA-E2, (2001-07), 4.3D, 125/170,"
    ),
    array(
        "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "UNIMOG/WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-E3, (2001-12), 4.3D, 130/177,"
    ),
    array(
        "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "TRUCK, OM904LA-EPA98, (2002-07), 4.3D, 127/173,"
    ),
    array(
        "MERCEDES-BENZ",
        "ATEGO1418/1518, OM904LA, 4.3D, 127/173,"
    ),
    array(
        "FREIGHTLINER",
        "OM904LA-MEXICO, (2000-03), 4.3D, 127/173,"
    ),
    array(
        "FREIGHTLINER",
        "WALK-INVAN, OM904LA-EPA, (2001-05), 4.3D, 135/184"
    ),
);

$cars_sorted = [];

foreach($cars as $car){
    $cars_sorted[$car[0]] .= $car[1];
}

var_dump($cars_sorted);
```

Comment: Да спасибо, все подошло!

Comment: `$cars as [$key, $value]`